# Implement Oauth 1.0a with php (shared server)

Tags: php, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to send some data to an app, and they using Oauth 1.0a , but i never use it.
I tryed to look here for some help and i tryed to look for tutos too but i didnt understand anything.
I found this link : http://oauth.net/code/

But honestly i didnt understand how to.
The api use Oauth1.0a «2-legged»

```
$conskey = '<key>';
$conssec = '<secret>';
try {
$oauth = new OAuth($conskey, $conssec, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
$oauth->enableDebug();
$data = new stdClass();
...
$ret = $oauth->fetch('url', json_encode($data), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
}
```

if someone can help how to use Oauth1.0a with php , and if it's possible to use it with codeigniter 3.
Thank you.

Comment: I assure you no, I read a lot of articles and did a lot of research

Comment: So you read the spec and came up empty? Because the alternative is that I read the spec. Which I have no reason to do.

Comment: yes but how to use the class OAuth, since it s not a native PHP class. Must I add something to my site and if yes how to call

Comment: OAuth2.0 is not a native PHP class either. Something you would have realized if you did any exhaustive research. Dont seems like you prefer APIs